# How To Hide Rows 16 rows above and 13 rows below in a cell where it has a value that says Bar is Already Terminated In Excel

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Button210_Click()
Dim r As Long
For r = 1 To 1500 Step 30
    Rows(r - 16 & ":" & r + 13).Hidden = Cells(r, "C").Value = "Bar Already Terminated"
Next
End Sub
```

The code above returns Type Mismatch. Im new in vba, please help. Thanks

Comment: You need to start at row 17 or the first loop will try to do `Rows("-15:14")` and there are no negative rows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried editing it, but it still didnt hide the cells. Btw the cells contains if functions that returns "Bar Already Terminated" if the value returns false to some other reference cells. Does it affect the result?

Comment: So the error is gone?

Comment: Yes, I just dont know why it still doesnt work huhu, anyway I'll do some twicks then I'll get back to you if it works. thanks again! :D